# SUM and FORMAT combined MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask how to combine sum and format at the same time. I want to have a comma separation if the sum of my data is one thousand or greater.

My sum in sql:

```
     SELECT SUM(cost) FROM table
```

Format:

```
     SELECT FORMAT(`cost`, 2) FROM table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
 SELECT FORMAT(SUM(cost), 2)
 FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT FORMAT(Sum(cost), 2) FROM table1
```

or:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Col,2) FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(cost) AS Col FROM table1
)AS T
```